# How do I get help on apt-get's install subcommand?

Tags: command-line, apt, manpage

I tried with `apt-get help install` and `apt-get install --help`, but I keep getting the main `apt-get` help page offering scarce information on the install subcommand:

```
install - Install new packages (pkg is libc6 not libc6.deb)
```

Where could I read on `--no-install-recommends` and other available options?

Comment: If you do not understand a specific command you can also get some hints here: [explainshell](http://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=apt-get+install)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First run:

```
man apt-get
```

Now, when you are inside manual page of `apt-get`, type <kbd>/</kbd> followed by the word/phrase to search for it and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For example:

- if you are interested about `install`, type `/install` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- if you are interested about `--no-install-recommends`, type `/--no-install-recommends` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After, you can use <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for the next and previous matches.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I am still perplexed as to why isn't this option listed under `apt-get -h` then or in the manpage synopsis. This way I really have to go reading through the whole manpage to find any options relevant to the install subcommand (luckily I roughly knew what this one was called, but new users might not).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've already tagged your question with the answer: `manpage`.
Run from the terminal:

```
man apt-get
```